# Css for results page with 3 columns

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm struggling with a 3 columns css item. It's for a search results page. There are 3 blocks, one for image, one for text and the last one for the price (and other infos).

Everything is working with the middle column doesn't contains too much text. But once I have more text the column 2 takes the full width and cause a line break.

See images.

Here is the code :

CSS:

```
#results { width:100%; }
#results .item { background-color:#FFFFFF; width:100%; border:1px solid #e9e9e9; float:left;}
#results .item:hover { background-color:#f2faff; border:1px solid #e7f6ff}
#results img { padding:10px; float:left}
#results .info {  padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;  height:100px; float:left}
#results .info .title {  font-size:18px; font-weight:700; color:#000000;     }
#results .info .subtitle {  font-size:16px; font-weight:200; color:#000000;  }
#results .info .description {  font-size:14px; font-weight:200; color:#666; margin-top:8px; }
#results .price {  padding:10px 20px 10px 10px; border-left:1px solid #e9e9e9; height:100px; float:right}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<a href="#" itemprop="url">
    <img src="/images/ads/87/1_130x100.jpg" width="130" height="100" itemprop="image" alt="">   
    <div class="info">
        <div class="title" itemprop="name">this is a beautiful title</div>
        <div class="subtitle" itemprop="description">This a beautiful sub title</div>
        <div class="description">
            Dimensions 400 cm x 800 cm. Coloris blanc. Hauteur : 300 cm. Structure en acier finition poudre polyester.Toile polyethylène (PE) 140 gr/m². 
            4 rideaux. Sardines de fixation au sol incluses.
            Ferme sur les 4 cotés.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="price">200 Dollars</div>
</a>
</div>
```

See screenshots :

1. http://content.screencast.com/users/LioH_/folders/Jing/media/c46a638f-1cc6-4e20-ba8b-76721d7264f2/notcool.png
2. http://content.screencast.com/users/LioH_/folders/Jing/media/0ee8b19e-1950-4860-9000-87c130c2c460/cool.png

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the `float` property on `.info`
2. Put the `<div class="price">...</div>` before the `<div class="info">...</div>`  in the html markup.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y46gZ/11/)**.

This will keep the reponsiveness of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you columns are missing a `width`.  You've done the right thing by floating them but you need to give them a width which could be a `%` or in `px`.  Something like

```
#results img {
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    width: 100px; /* Added width */
}
#results .info {
    padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    width: 200px; /* Added width */
}
#results .price {
    padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;
    border-left:1px solid #e9e9e9;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px; /* Added width */
    float:right
}
```

If you're defining the width in pixels like I have done you need to take into account the width of any parent div's and also any padding applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
.item a {
  display: flex;
  display: ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some width to the class info

ie.

```
#results .info {
padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
width: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make middle .info block float:none and margin left and right with size of image and price block:

```
#results img { 
    width:150px;/*fixed or percent size here*/
    padding:10px; 
    float:left;         
}
#results .price { 
    width:150px;/*fixed or percent size here*/ 
    float:right; 
    padding:10px 20px 10px 10px; border-left:1px solid #e9e9e9; height:100px; 
}

#results .info { 
    float:none; /*float none!*/
    margin-left:160px; /* width of img here*/
    margin-right:160px; /* width of price here*/
    padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;  height:100px;
}
```